# UNIX command for record count at one go

Tags: shell, unix

Please help me with the command to get the record count of files in a directory. I know wc -l filename will give me the count , but is there a single command to display record count for all files in the directory at one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is:

```
wc -l /dirname/*
```

If you have directories inside `/dirname/` you'll see some errors about trying to apply `wc` to a directory. In that case you can use:

```
find /dirname/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs wc -l
```

Or if you want to go full recursive:

```
find /dirname/ -type f | xargs wc -l
```